# Finding and changing measurement units using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, measurements

Using QGIS 2.4, I want to create 1,000m buffer around an object, but when I enter 1,000 as the distance I get something that looks more like a 100,000m buffer.

I can enter 0.01 to get what looks like a 1,000m buffer, but I would rather work in single metres.

How do I change the settings so that the number I enter is in single metres?

Comment: Please indicate what software you're using, a sensible answer would depend very much on that.

Comment: Thanks, I have added that to title.  I thought QGIS had been added automatically, but alas...

Comment: Do you have a projection system set? Maybe the units are degrees now.

Comment: I'm guessing the data have units of degrees, since 0.01 degrees is about 1,113 m at the equator. Reproject to a CRS that is in metres.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that?